# Granting access to a support employee in a multi-tenant Azure AD application environment

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I recently migrated an Azure Active Directory application from single-tenant to multi-tenant. Our application is now used by different companies, and we utilize Microsoft login with the common endpoint. Previously, when it was single-tenant, a company added our support engineers as guests to their Active Directory, granting them the "Support" role in our enterprise application. This meant that they could log into production using their work email address and all would work well!

However, in the new multi-tenant setup, our support engineers are unable to access the application in the production environment because our tenantId is not part of the authorized tenants. Simply adding our tenantId to the list of authorized tenants would not work, because the support engineer wants to access the application for that specific company tenant, not our own; we aren't using the application ourselves.

Additionally, if multiple companies have added our support engineer as a guest, how can the application determine which tenant they want to log in to? A solution could be to ask each company to create a seperate email addresses for each support engineer, however this seems inconvenient and potentially insecure.

I would greatly appreciate any advice or solutions to address this issue!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to introduce the functionality in your application to switch tenants (like the way you do in Azure Portal).

Just thinking out loud, your support engineers would login into the application. By default they would login into your Azure AD (home tenant). Your application can then conditionally check if the logged in user is the support engineer who may need to switch the tenant.

Using [`Tenants - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list?tabs=HTTP) API, you can get the list of tenants the user is a member of and then ask the user to select the tenant in which they want to login. Once they switch the tenant, you will need to acquire a new access token for your application in that tenant and proceed to use the application.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav! Thank you for your comment. Your recommendation sounds like a good solution, though I was hoping something like this would be implemented into the Azure AD login flow natively.. One more question: To access such a "tenant picker" in the application means that you would already need to be authorized to access the application in the first place; or implement a different "flow" for the picker. Any good ideas for this?

Comment: `I was hoping something like this would be implemented into the Azure AD login flow natively` - AFAIK, such thing does not exist natively. `To access such a "tenant picker" in the application means that you would already need to be authorized to access the application in the first place` - That is correct. `or implement a different "flow" for the picker` - I am not sure I understand this. Would you mind explaining please?

Comment: It's a chicken and egg problem. You need to be logged in to access the "Tenant Switcher", but you can't log in because your tenant isn't an authorized tenant, that is why we want to access the tenant switcher.

The employees are from Tenant A, the company we want to support is from Tenant B. When we log in to the application with our accounts from Tenant A, the application doesn't recognize our tenant and we get kicked out. I guess we would need to allow our support employees to log in and only use the tenant switcher, without doing any API calls that require a real tenant.

Comment: Does your application uses a single URL or does each client gets their own URL? How are your support engineers get onboarded on the client application?

Comment: The application runs on www.application.com. all tenants access it from there and are shown a microsoft login prompt. Support engineers are onboarded by using the our test environment which is hosted on a sifferent URL, which uses 2 "application test tenants" we created ourselves. So they log in with admin-foo@faketenant.com", for example. Or perhaps user-bob@faketenant2.com to try out the application from another perspective.